# Address sanitizer ignorelist not working with visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use address-sanitizer with visual studio 2019 (version 16.9.2).
 I would like 
to ignore some of the errors generated by address-sanitizer as they are emitted from external
libraries.

When I use /fsanitize-ignorelist=D:\asan_blacklist.txt in 
Configuration Properties->C/C++->Command Line->Additional Options 
***/fsanitize-ignorelist=D:\asan_blacklist.txt*** 
Then I get following error message 
command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/fsanitize-ignorelist=D:\asan_blacklist.txt'

I've also tried ***/fsanitize-blacklist=D:\asan_blacklist.txt*** option but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, according to the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-building#compiler), the Visual Studio compiler currently only supports these options:

- `/fsanitize=address`
- `/fsanitize=fuzzer`
- `/fsanitize-address-use-after-return`